# Does anyone knows what "rimraf" means?

Tags: node.js, semantics

Ok for the recursive options when deleting files, but what is `rimraf`?
Is it an acronym? Does it come from words combination?

The word is fairly pleasant, I would like to know where does it come from.

Comment: maybe [RimRaf](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/javascript/nodejs/how-to-delete-node_modules-folder-on-windows-machine/). Seems it is just easy to pronounce _rimraf_ than _rm -rf_

Comment: I'd guess it originated as an attempt to pronounce "`rm -rf`"

Comment: Hehe @Joseph Merdrignac ...  Funny thing is... being a writer among other things, I also find "the word is" (indeed) "fairly pleasant". Gonna name my next kid Rimraf :D. "Hey Rimraf, please remove all your toys from the floor. Recursively!" --- It's going to be a great success :D.

Comment: I also find it has a pleasant quality to the word. I feel very satisfied when I say the word.

Comment: @Axonn So, how's little Rimraf Asterisk doing?

Answer (score 183):

**Rimraf**

The UNIX command rm -rf for **Node.js**

Deep deletion (like `rm -rf`) module for **Node.js** that provides asynchronous deep- deletion of files and directories.

The `rimraf` executable is a faster alternative to the `rm -rf` shell command.

(`rm` stands for **r**e**m**ove, `rf` stands for **r**ecursive **f**orce.)

Source :

- https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf
- https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Rimraf

Comment: One thing that has to be understood in the context of the rimraf context as an npm package is its intended usage. It's not like you can't rm -rf in Linux and call it a day, but Windows won't understand your intent. As such rather then thinking about it as a faster alias, you can think about it as a cross platform solution for the same problem: rm -rf.

Comment: btw, don't forget to install it globally using `npm` or in your current project before using it :)

Comment: Don't install globally. Install it locally with `npm install --save-dev rimraf`, then use it with `npx`: `npx rimraf some-file` Or use it in the `scripts` section of *package.json*

Answer (score 63):

It is a way to pronounce the command `rm -rf` (remove, recursive, force removal).

Answer (score 31):

`rimraf` is an executable that is used to clean the installed node packages in a node based project. It basically executes the `rm -rf` command on the `node_modules` directory, but is a faster alternative.

Comment: Why and how much is it faster than `rm -rf`?

Comment: @k0pernikus around -50% (2 times slower than `rm -rf`) on my machine and for some others too, like measured here http://www.ashleysheridan.co.uk/blog/Why+You+Should+Not+Use+Rimraf ; sometimes there is no difference, and sometimes it's around 50 times slower than `rm -rf`, according to this issue: https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf/issues/142

Answer (score 14):

> isaacs: It's how I pronounce `rm -rf`

from https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf/issues/175

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, it's based on rm -rf. However, I think pronunciation sounds like it may come from the [term](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/riffraff) riffraff, or perhaps even [the rapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riff_Raff_(rapper)) Riff Raff (just kidding).

And I say this as a possible explanation for the added "i" and "a" in "rimraf" since that coincides with the word riffraff.